# How to get the row and col position by hovering over a cell in a data table using R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have data in the following format:

```
Fruits  ID
Apple   1
Orange  2
Banana  3
Melon   4
Guava   5
Mango   6
Avocado 7
Grape   8
```

I am trying to plot a table  of the IDs as shown below with different colors assigned to the cells based on the ID Number.

[image]

When the user hovers on a cell, the corresponding Fruit should display preferably in a table or at least as a tool tip.

[image]

Comment: I call the data which is in csv format and output it to DT::datatable for display after some processing. I am able to get the row and column coordinates using input$TitleID_cell_clicked and display the results to another table dynamically. But I would like to get the column and row  coordinates while hovering over a cell because when clicked on a cell it is selecting the whole row which is misleading. Hope I was clear!

Comment: We want to see your code ;) In case you didnt know it yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1